# Android: Use different layouts in ListFragment using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment, findviewbyid

Hello everyone and thank you for reading my question!

I'm currently developing an android app that has the following hierarchy:
One `FragmentActivity` is divided by three `ListFragments`. 
One of these `ListFragments` uses a custom `ArrayAdapter` to display a `List<>` with a xml template on a `ListView`
This `List<>` is filled with dataset which are given id's. Datasets with id's lower than 10 are flagged "important", the other ones are flagged "not so important"

This is what I am looking for: 
I have two layout templates, and I want to display the "important" datasets with one layout and the "not so important" with the other layout.

I have searched for quite a while now, but it looks like noone has asked a question like this before. 
I tried to use a second `ListView` and apply a second custom `ArrayAdapter` on it, but unfortunately, there is a restriction: Since I'm using `ListFragment`, I'm forced to use `findViewById` like this.

```
ListView list;
list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

When I tried to write the second custom `ArrayAdapter`, it showed an error here:

```
ListView list;
list_flat = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list_flat);
```

Here is the entire `ListFragment`

```
public class LeaguePage extends ListFragment{
    Global global_var;
    ListView list, list_flat;
    List <League> leagues = null;
    ListAdapter adapter = null;
    View rootView;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.league_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
       }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    list_flat = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list_flat);
    try {
        leagues = Leagues_Parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("league_raw.xml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter = new LeagueAdapter (getActivity(), R.layout.list_row, leagues);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
       {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Global.selectedTeam = Integer.valueOf(leagues.get(arg2).getInternalID());
            Global.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
       });
}
```

}

**This is the xml file I pass on to my** `ArrayAdapter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/liga_flat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom ="10dip"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the xml layout file for the** `ListFragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main_Activity$search_page" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main_Activity$search_page" >
<ListView
  android:id="@id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:dividerHeight="0dp"
  android:divider="@null">
  </ListView>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context=".Main_Activity$search_page" >

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/android:list2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:divider="@null"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
      </ListView>
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't give a `ListView` an ID like this :`android:id="@+id/android:list2"`, the ID of your `ListView` should be

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"   
...... ></ListView>
```

or

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/sampleList"   
...... ></ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! 
Very true! But then again, I already have a `ListView` with the line `android:id="@id/android:list"` in this xml file

Comment: android:id="@id/android:list" is same as the first pattern in the answer, if you have another list,use the second pattern, instead of android:id="@+id/android:list2", use android:id="@+id/list2"

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't simply use another list in a `ListFragment`. Maybe I can add a list into the `ListFragment`? I can't add a View to my list, it says "This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException". It seems like I need to move away from my `ListFragment` to a standard Fragment

Comment: Maybe two different ListFragments, because if you want a List there, you have to use ListFragment instead of Fragment, if you only have one ListView for each fragment, you don't need to worry that all the ListViews have the same IDs, you can give all the ListView IDs in the first pattern

Comment: So you are telling me that I can use two `ListFragments` which I can display on one page?

Comment: Interesting! I'll check how that'll work with my SectionsPagerAdapter! Thank you Zhenxiao Hao!